# Chef Kitchen + Vagrant Window7 box failing due to SSH

Tags: windows, vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen

LOG INFO:

```
 -----> Starting Kitchen (v1.2.1)
 -----> Creating <default-windows>...
   Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
   ==> default: Importing base box 'windows'...
   ==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
   ==> default: Setting the name of the VM: default-   windows_default_1422548310230_74071
   ==> default: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2202.
   ==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
   ==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
       default: Adapter 1: nat
       default: Adapter 2: hostonly
   ==> default: Forwarding ports...
       default: 22 => 2202 (adapter 1)
   ==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...           default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2202
       default: SSH username: vagrant
       default: SSH auth method: private key
       default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
       default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
       default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
       default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

MY kitchen.yml:

```
---
driver_plugin: vagrant
driver_config:
  require_chef_omnibus: true
  network:
  - ['private_network', {ip: '192.168.33.33'}]

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

platforms:
  - name: windows
    driver:
      box: windows
      communicator: winrm
    driver_config:
      gui: true

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[tcserver::java-for-tcserver]
      - recipe[tcserver::default]
    attributes:
```

$ vagrant box list

```
bseller/santiago      (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
chef/centos-6.5       (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
chef/centos-6.5       (vmware_desktop, 1.0.0)
chef/ubuntu-14.04     (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
hashicorp/precise32   (virtualbox, 1.0.0)
hashicorp/precise64   (virtualbox, 1.1.0) 
learningchef/centos65 (virtualbox, 1.0.7)
opscode-centos-6.5    (virtualbox, 0) 
opscode-ubuntu-12.04  (virtualbox, 0)
opscode-ubuntu-14.04  (virtualbox, 0)
pcf-immersion-box     (virtualbox, 0)
suse/sles11sp3        (virtualbox, 0.1.7) 
ubuntu-chef           (virtualbox, 0)
ubuntu-ruby-chef      (virtualbox, 0)
ubuntu/trusty32       (virtualbox, 14.04)
ubuntu1204            (virtualbox, 0)
vista-ie7             (virtualbox, 0)
windows               (virtualbox, 0)
windows8              (virtualbox, 0)
```

My generated Vagrantfile from `kitchen converge`

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |c|
  c.vm.box = "windows"
  c.vm.box_url = "https://opscode-vm-    bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/virtualbox/opscode_windows_chef-provisionerless.box"
  c.vm.hostname = "default-windows.vagrantup.com"
  c.vm.network(:private_network, {:ip=>"192.168.33.33"})
  c.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  c.vm.provider :virtualbox do |p|
  end
end
```

I'm able to successfully run a kitchen converge on a centos/rhel/ubuntu box. This seems to totally be a windows issue (like usual).

It appears that my directives in kitchen.yml are not being translated to the Vagrantfile.

Following runs of `kitchen converge` indicate VM is running but unable to connect:

```
[SSH] connection failed, retrying (#<Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host>)
```

Comment: After a quick search on google I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574387/why-is-vagrant-trying-to-ssh-to-windows-guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this excellent blog post](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/peering-into-the-future-of-windows-automation-testing-with-chef-vagrant-and-test-kitchen-look-mom-no-ssh) from Matt Wrock, you need to use cutting edge test-kitchen and kitchen-vagrant. With all credit to Matt Wrock, he helped me [figure out which versions](https://gist.github.com/amaltson/f763531bb2689ad311ed#comment-1385660).

The tl;dr is:

- Use the [windows-guest-support branch of test-kitchen](https://github.com/test-kitchen/test-kitchen/tree/windows-guest-support)
- Use the [Transport branch of kitchen-vagrant](https://github.com/afiune/kitchen-vagrant/tree/Transport)

If you're using a `Gemfile` in your cookbook, you can use Bundler's [git dependency](http://bundler.io/git.html) support to pull in these correct branches/forks. If you're using only Chef-DK without Bundler, you'll need to replace the Chef-DK shipped test-kitchen and kitchen-vagrant